# RequirePackage and usepretex from latexmk change output file to texput.tex

Tags: include, latexmk, etoolbox, makefile

I want to compile a larger file completly based on a toggle (`my@final`) from the commandline using a `makefile`.

My `.tex`-file looks like:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{01.tex}
  Hello, world
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{02.tex}
  foo, bar
\end{filecontents}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\providetoggle{my@final}
\providecommand*{\InfoTeX}{Compiler}
\iftoggle{my@final}{}{
  \includeonly{
   % 01,
    02
  }
}

\begin{document}
Start
\InfoTeX
\include{01}
\include{02}
End
\end{document}
```

Since I need also `biber` etc. for the proper file I would like to go with `latexmk` and its option `-usepretex`, so I dont have to worry about calling `biber` etc. manually.

The makefile:

```
PROJECT=mydocument
LATEX  =lualatex
COMPILER_INFO=$(shell $(LATEX)  -v | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f3-)
LATEX_FINAL=\RequirePackage{etoolbox}\providetoggle{my@final}\toggletrue{my@final}
LATEX_OPTS   =\newcommand*\InfoTeX{$(COMPILER_INFO)}
LATEXMK = latexmk -$(LATEX) -usepretex="$(LATEX_OPTS)"


all:
#   pdf: mydocument.pdf
    time latexmk -gg -$(LATEX) -usepretex="$(LATEX_OPTS)" $(PROJECT).tex


final:
#   pdf: texput.pdf
    time latexmk -gg -$(LATEX) -usepretex="$(LATEX_OPTS)$(LATEX_FINAL)" $(PROJECT).tex
```

I get the proper pdf (`mydocument.pdf`) when I call `make`. But this is based on the `includeonly` and which chapters are activated.
With `make final` I want to get the whole document regardless of the `includeonly`-command.
But now, using `\RequirePackage...` the output file is changed to `texput.pdf` and the process aborts:

```
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
```

How can I get the complete `mydocument.pdf` with calling `make final`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give latexmk a -jobname argument:

```
time latexmk -jobname=$(PROJECT) -gg -$(LATEX) -usepretex="$(LATEX_OPTS)$(LATEX_FINAL)" $(PROJECT).tex
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the boolean I found the `\newif` and it turns out that it works. But still the credit for answering the question goes to [John Collins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655658/98739).

For the sake of completeness and as an alternative approach, I post a different solution:

`mydocument.tex`:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{01.tex}
  Hello, world
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{02.tex}
  foo, bar
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{scrbook}
\providecommand*{\InfoTeX}{Compiler}
\ifPartsOnly
  \includeonly{
   % 01,
    02
  }
\else
\fi
\begin{document}
Start
\InfoTeX
\include{01}
\include{02}
End
\end{document}
```

`makefile`:

```
PROJECT=mydocument
LATEX  =lualatex
COMPILER_INFO=$(shell $(LATEX)  -v | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f3-)
LATEX_FINAL=\newif\ifPartsOnly\PartsOnlyfalse
LATEX_OPTS   =\newif\ifPartsOnly\PartsOnlytrue\newcommand*\InfoTeX{$(COMPILER_INFO)}
LATEXMK = latexmk -$(LATEX) -usepretex="$(LATEX_OPTS)"


all:
#   pdf: mydocument.pdf
    time latexmk -gg -$(LATEX) -usepretex="$(LATEX_OPTS)" $(PROJECT).tex


final:
#   pdf: mydocument.pdf
    time latexmk -gg -$(LATEX) -usepretex="$(LATEX_OPTS)$(LATEX_FINAL)" $(PROJECT).tex
```

Both commands (`make` and `make final`) compile the document `mydocument.tex` and give back `mydocument.pdf`.

Comment: For most situations, this is a better solution: In the pretex code, use only basic TeX or LaTeX commands to define something, and then let the document itself deal with the logic of what to do, including deciding what packages to use.